# Baud Rate Generator

Tags: baudrate

I came across a block called **Baud rate generator** when reading about the TIVA UART module. I also came across the below formula for calculating the **Baud rate divisor**,

> Baud Rate Divisor = UARTSysClk/ (ClkDiv * Baud Rate)

Please let me know the following,

1. What is a baud rate generator and how it works?
2. What is baud rate divisor and how does the above formula work?
3. Why is a baud rate generator module needed in UART Modules?

Comment: 1. "what is it": it generates a clock signal for the UART, as the name suggests. More info: see said module's datasheet. 2. it's a divider. I can't tell you how division works. That's just math. It's the way we define *numbers* that allow us to define the operation "division" on them, but I really don't think doing fundamental algebra here is of any benefit. 3. see 1.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> What is a baud rate generator and how it works?

It's a clock generator which is used to determine the rate at which data is transmitted by a UART. It works by taking a relatively high frequency clock (higher clock frequencies are much smaller and cheaper than normal UART frequencies) and dividing down to the desired frequency. Conceptually, it looks like

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fnXCj7.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>

> What is baud rate divisor and how does the above formula work?

Let's start with your original formula

Baud Rate Divisor = UARTSysClk/ (ClkDiv * Baud Rate)

and rearrange the terms a bit

Baud Rate = UARTSysClk/ (ClkDiv * Baud Rate Divisor)

Where the right-hand side is the "Divide by N" in the block diagram.

Generally, UARTSysClk is a very high frequency, so the right-hand term needs to be quite large. Rather than have a series of selectable large divisors to get the desired baud rate, it is cheaper to a have a single large divisor followed by a selectable small divisor. This will work because standard UART frequencies are related by factors of two.

As an example, let's say you have a SysClk of 2,457,600 and you want an output of either 9600 baud or 19,200 baud. If you do this the hard way, you'll need a divide by 128 to get 19,200 baud, and 256 to get 9600.

Instead, you can use a single 128, then follow it by a divide by 2 to get 9600, and select whichever you want. This is easily represented as a ClkDiv of 128, and a BaudRateDivisor of either 1 or 2.

> Why is a baud rate generator module needed in UART Modules?

Just because the basic processor uses a much higher frequency for its clock that a UART does, and the processor only needs a single frequency, while the UART needs several selectable frequencies.

Answer (score 2):

I'm sure you are well aware of common UART baud rates such as 9600 baud, 57600 baud and so on. That means 9600 bits per second and 57600 bits per second respectively. That needs something like an interrupt to occur at 9600Hz or 57600Hz respectively.

System clocks are typically in MHz which is far too quick for the UART speeds mentioned above, so the system clock needs to be divided down. Normally baud rate generator is implemented using a counter, which when either overflows (if incremented) or reaches zero (if decremented), issues an interrupt to the UART which will output the next bit for transmission. Or probably a counter with fewer bits for sampling at receive end.

The value ClkDiv is restricted by the hardware typically, for Tiva UART you have, and from limited info I've read on Tiva UART I find clock divs of 8 or 16 available.

Lets say the UART sys clk is 80MHz (I'm just guessing by reading Tiva UART info -- that's pretty high) -- And we choose clkdiv of 16 and want baud rate of 57600. Then `Baud Rate Divisor = 80000000/ (16 * 57600)` so `Baud rate divisor` is `86.8056` which should be set in some register of the Tiva UART.

Registers are typically integers. So it will need to be `87` as integer. If you have a smaller baud rate you will have a larger divisor. You need to be careful not to have a divisor too large that it won't overflow the divisor register. (for example the value `300` will overflow an 8-bit register)

Because it is an integer there will be some error. The error is:

`(80000000 / 87) / 16` = `57471.2` which is about 0.2% error from `57600`, not bad. It doesn't need to be 0% but the closer the better.

Choosing a smaller clock divider will reduce the error with certain baud rates.

Anyway by setting the `baud rate divisor` with the correct value, it will essentially create a timer at the correct baud rate for transmission (and perhaps reception with a counter a few bits shorter for sampling) Sampling is normally done 16 times quicker than the baud so a counter 4 bits shorter will do the trick

Answer (score 1):

1) It is a module that somehow uses the available clocks to divide down a clock that is used for bit transmission and reception.

2) If the CPU clock is 2 MHz and UART bit rate is 9600, the UART needs usally a clock of 16x9600 for oversampling the received data. Therefore a divisor for the baud rate generator is 13 in this case.

3) Again, to get the baud rate you want from the clocks you happen to have. Otherwise you can't get the baud rates you need.