# How do I diagnose problems with serial port communication between a PC and a Blackboard?

Tags: uart, serial, xilinx, zynq, vitis

I am trying to write an application that runs on a [Blackboard](https://www.realdigital.org/doc/9c908d94497abb1eac41175d1ab05b88) and it is supposed to send/receive characters to/from the PC COM port. The application on the PC is Xilinx 'Visits Serial Terminal'.

In Xilinx on the PC, I've written a C program that is using UART1 addresses to configure the baud rate, parity, etc and then sends a character. Then, I build/deploy/run this program to the board through the USB cable.

Then, in Windows Device Manager, I make sure that the COM4 port is configured to match the settings in my C program.

Finally, I use Xilinx 'Vitis Serial Terminal' to connect to the same COM4 using the same settings as well.

The problem is that I do not see any data in the 'Vitis Serial Terminal'.

My question is: how do I narrow/debug such problems?

There are many points of failures:

- My C program might be doing the wrong things.
- My Windows driver is acting weird/is misconfigured.
- My expectations/configurations of 'Vitis Serial Terminal' are wrong.

If there's a working sample that would be ideal and I can go from there.

I've found this [Real Digital](https://www.realdigital.org/doc/ef3498f424aaa1b20b5199907ba12b4c) article and have similar code in my C program. I've also tried to follow their `Backboard - Basic Zynq Programmers Reference - Rev B'. The data in there is accurate when used to access other functions of that board (leds, 7-segment, etc), so I think I'm using the right reference.

Below is my C program:

```
#define UART1_CONTROL_REGISTER   0xE0001000
#define UART1_MODE               0xE0001004
#define UART1_BAUD_GEN           0xE0001018
#define UART1_BAUD_RATE_DIVIDER  0xE0001034
#define UART1_RXTOUT             0xE000101C
#define IDR_REGISTER             0xE0005028

#define UART1_SR                 0xE000102C
#define UART1_DATA               0xE0001030

void ConfigureUART1()
{
    // https://www.realdigital.org/doc/ef3498f424aaa1b20b5199907ba12b4c

    // Reset the UART Controller
    //      bit 0: 1 -> receiver logic is reset/data discarded.
    //      bit 1: 1 -> transmitted logic is reset/data discarded.
    //      bit 2: 1 -> enable receive.
    //      bit 3: 0 -> don't disable receive.
    //      bit 4: 1 -> enable transmit.
    //      bit 5: 0 -> don't disable receive.
    //      bit 6: 1 -> restart timerout counter.
    //      bit 7: 0 -> no effect (else, start transmitting a 'break'.)
    //      bit 8: 0 -> no effect (else, stop transmitting a 'break'.)
    //               -> 0 0101 0111

    // Reset...
    * ((uint32_t*)UART1_CONTROL_REGISTER) = 0x3;

    // Wait till they clear again
    while (*((uint32_t*)UART1_CONTROL_REGISTER) == 0x3){};

    // The following divider values we given by the instructor.
    // Based on this post https://electronics.stackexchange.com/questions/442404/baud-rate-generator,
    // the values might be incorrect when our board's clock is 333MHz.

    // Set the BAUDGEN clock divider (115200 baud works well; 0x7C divider value)
    *((uint32_t*)UART1_BAUD_GEN) = 0x7C;

    // Set the Baud_Rate_Divider for bit-clock (again for 115200, 0x6 works)
    *((uint32_t*)UART1_BAUD_RATE_DIVIDER) = 0x6;

    // Channel mode to normal, 1 stop bit, no parity, character length 8-bit, clock source to UART reference clock (Mode Register)
    //      bit 0    : 0   -> clock source is uart_ref_clk
    //      bit 1-2  : 0x  -> 8 bits
    //      bit 3-5  : 1xx -> no parity
    //      bit 6-7  : 00  -> 1 stop bit
    //      bit 8-9  : 00  -> normal
    //      bit 10-11: reserved, do not modify.
    //           0b   dddd-rr 00--00 100 00 0
    //           0x      0c     --     20
    //               0x00000c00 reserved
    //               0x00000020
    uint32_t v0 = *((uint32_t*)UART1_MODE);
    uint32_t v1 = 0x00000c00 & v0;
    *((uint32_t*)UART1_MODE) = v1 | 0x20;

    // Configure the UART Controller
    // Enable software resets, transmitter & receiver, stop transmitter break (Control Register)
    //      bit 0: 0 -> receiver logic is reset/data discarded.
    //      bit 1: 0 -> transmitted logic is reset/data discarded.
    //      bit 2: 1 -> enable receive.
    //      bit 3: 0 -> don't disable receive.
    //      bit 4: 1 -> enable transmit.
    //      bit 5: 0 -> don't disable receive.
    //      bit 6: 0 -> restart timerout counter.
    //      bit 7: 0 -> no effect (else, start transmitting a 'break'.)
    //      bit 8: 0 -> no effect (else, stop transmitting a 'break'.)
    //               -> 0 0001 0100
    *((uint32_t*)UART1_CONTROL_REGISTER) = 0x14;

    // Set timeout to 1 (RXTOUT register)
    //      bit 0-7: 1-255 timeout in number ob baud_samples clocks.
    *((uint32_t*)UART1_RXTOUT) = 0x1;

    // Disable all interrupts (IDR register)
    //      bit 0-9: 1 -> disable this interrupt.
    *((uint32_t*)IDR_REGISTER) = 0xFFFFFFFF;
}

int IsTxFull()
{
    //Check SR register bit4, return 1 if fifo full
    return (*((uint32_t*)UART1_SR) & 0x10) != 0;
}

void Uart1PutChar(char dat)
{
    // Wait for room in FIFO
    while (IsTxFull());

    // Write to TX FIFO
    *((uint32_t*)UART1_DATA) = dat;
}

int main()
{
    ConfigureUART1();
    while (1)
        Uart1PutChar('A');
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because it's not an Electrical Engineering question. It's about writing PC software.

Comment: This may be just a case of pins 2 and 3 swapped in the cabling.  Check that before you go any further. Pin 5 is ground.  TXD will be at some negative voltage more than -3V.  RXD will be at some positive voltage perhaps 1V Make sure you go RXD to TXD

Comment: Thx @KenSmith - the board is hard-wired though, so I assume it is correct.